# Why does Lightroom 4 CR2 "Edit in Photoshop" make a TIF file?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-cs5, lightroom-4, raw

when I right-click an image (CR2) and select "Edit in Photoshop" Lightroom first creates a TIF. Can I turn this off? Or what is the point? Is this actually useful? 
I normally optimize the Raw-File in Lightroom, open it in Photoshop and edit it a little and then save it as a PSD. Is TIF more preferable? Or why does Lightroom do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12655/is-it-better-to-store-edited-photos-as-psd-or-tiff-files/12666#12666 includes a discussion of the relative merits of TIFF over PSD.

Comment: I always create TIFFs from CR2 files, but after PS editing I save them as PSDs.

Comment: Try this: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/22533/1359

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit->Preferences->External Editing. There you should be able to choose the desired format (TIFF or PSD)

[Here's](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/lightroom/using/WSA810DC18-9A3B-4f2e-B09C-1C45DD1F8EDC.html) more info on this from Adobe.

Concerning the advantage of TIFF over PSD, see Conor Boyd's comment!

Comment: There are quite a lot of advantages of TIFF over PSD; see the link in my comment above.

Comment: I have to admit I also did not know, that TIFF is so versatile as a container. As it can seemingly provide everything PSD can handle as well, I have to fully agree with you that TIFF seems to be the better choice. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: "Once you go TIFF, you never go back." - Someone from the Internet.